# Why are Indian news TV channels not showing coverage of cricket matches?

Tags: cricket, media

During earlier IPL events, all Indian news TV channels were giving highlights, point tables, etc. We were getting too many updates.

During IPL 2018, there was no coverage in prime time on any Indian news TV channels. Even the England tour was not shown. Now Asia Cup is not shown. No updates on cricket, except for a line or two. Even the India-Pakistan match was not highlighted!

The Asian Games were shown prominently, but not cricket. Are TV news channels boycotting cricket? Or are sports telecasters demanding too much money from TV news channels?

Even the matches between India and West Indies is not shown prominently. On Day 1, there was prime time news only about the century scored by Prithvi Shaw and no other player was mentioned. Maybe broadcasters have taken very exclusive rights and want viewers to watch sports channels for cricket news.

EDIT:
On 21/Nov/2018, morning, there was some news about India preparing for the t20 matches, and players were shown practicing; Not sure if that is stock video or current coverage.
Evening, there were only few lines about India losing by 4 runs due to DLS. No video of the match, no news about wickets, partnerships, Australia score, top scorers  ....

Possible Answer:
Pattern looks like news channels want to cover it, but they are not getting the live video; Maybe the charges are too high or the owners of the video want viewers to watch it through sports channels only.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has to do with the amount of people having interest in IPL. The broadcasting rights of IPL and International Cricket both sold by BCCI to STAR Sports can give you an insight of how popular is IPL and how people are connected to it. 
The Media channels in order to achieve TRPs are trying to cash in the event.

Comment: I am not getting this answer .... Are you saying there is **too much coverage** because too many people watch it and hence trps are high ? I am asking why there is **too little coverage** .... Are Indian News Channels boycotting Cricket ?

Comment: No they are not boycotting Cricket. It is the same story every year. And it has nothing to do with Cricket. For instance in Football, normal leagues and Champions league does not get coverage, but a World Cup or Euro does. Same goes for Tennis, only Grandslams are preferred. IPL, World Cup, Champions Trophy which have more prominence are covered.

Comment: "IPL, World Cup, Champions Trophy which have more prominence are covered." .... What I am saying is that this year, none of these were covered in News Channels. Not sure about last year, but 3-4 years ago, we were flooded with cricket news, expert analysis, IPL Points table, match schedules, auction news, etc. In 2018, not much cricket news, except for a comment or two. Of course, a viewer who watches only sports channels will not have any change, and will not know that news channels have reduced the coverage